# How to shorten this?: read first|| exit 1; (echo "$first"; cat) | $foo

Tags: shell, diff, pipe

The aim is to not even start $foo if there is no input.

This can be useful if foo="diff - xyz", and the input is missing or empty.
Otherwise, diff would output all of "xyz" as the difference.

The original problem is that "cat doesnotexist | diff - exists" outputs the content of "exists" (prefixed with ">"), while I want the entire pipe to fail.
My current solution is:

```
cat doesnotexist | (read first|| exit 1; (echo "$first"; cat) | diff - exists)
```

, but I would like a shorter one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[ -f doesnotexist ] && diff doesnotexist exists
```

I removed the pipe, it has no added value in your example. Strictly, this doesn't let the diff fail, it's just not executed.

Comment: Well, the input is on a remote node, and the diff is running locally, so using -f would be even more verbose than the title snippet. So the added value of the pipe is that it fetches the remote data. Its input looks like "ssh -x -e none -C who@where cat doesnotexist |", but this appeared as unneeded detail to me so I didn't tell. :-)

Comment: In that case you might use a "scp -C who@where:doesnotexist . && diff doesnotexist exists"

Comment: Yeah, I might as well. Need to clean up "doesnotexist" afterwards, but it is more direct. Thanks.